# AWS S3 file URL generation for user to download the file

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

How can we get the URL for the amazon S3 bucket files. I have tried to get the file by below format

```
http://s3-REGION-.amazonaws.com/BUCKET-NAME/KEY
```

This format will be helpful to download the file if it has public access and server side encryption is disabled.

Purpose of URL generation is to share with internal teams in my organization. This file might have exceptions of any applications.

I have to make the file or the bucket to be restricted to my organization (not for public). The bucket what ever I have server side encryption is enabled. How can we generate the file url which has server side encryption is enabled ?

Comment: The client does not have to do anything special to decrypt an object if you are using S3's native server-side encryption. The object is encrypted at rest but decrypted for you, on demand.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate a presigned URL for an S3 object: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/presign.html

Presigned URLs can be generated programmatically as well with all AWS SDKs.

For example in Java: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURLJavaSDK.html

Answer (score 0):

if you are using .net aws sdk to generate predesign url

```
 var s3Client = new AmazonS3Client();

 var request1 = new GetPreSignedUrlRequest
            {
                BucketName = "bucketName",
                Key = "filename(original one and no coding)",
                Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5)
            };
 var urlString = s3Client.GetPreSignedURL(request1);
```